# Install fail on new HDD for HP Notebook

Tags: system-installation, system

I am rying to load v 18.0 on a new HDD installed on an HP Notebook.
Using Rufus to create a bootable USB. During install,after the Logo screen, I receive the message:
"unable to find media containing live file system"
I tried both Disk Image and Free DOS  during USB burn.